# Restore SharePoint Site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, restore

I was following [this](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2017/10/29/save-publishing-site-as-template-the-right-way-using-pnp-provisioning/) to restore a site template on a different site collection. But it keeps on throwing an exception "[image: File not found]".

Please suggest what I am missing

Comment: On the new site collection... what type of site template did you use?  Is it the same as the site that you used to create the template?

Comment: See I made a template of Site1(Say https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename1) and wants to deploys that template on a new site(Say https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename2). Is it possible no??

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue using Joao's code.  What fixed it for me was applying a different Template type.  Change

```
-Template "BLANKINTERNET#0"
```

to

```
-Template "STS#3"

$web = New-PnpWeb -Title "$siteTitle" -Url "$siteUrl" -Description "$siteDescription" -Locale 1033 -Template "STS#3"
```

Comment: I already have a site, what I need just deploy the template(template path shown in the screenshot).